# Ruby Script to color all sheets present in excel with a particular colour

Tags: ruby, excel, automation, win32ole

I need a ruby script to color all the sheets present in excel workbook with a fixed colour...all at once....
here i need to color this sheet with yellow color but the coloring should be only for cells with filled data.Something lik ethis

[image]

Comment: show some excel sheet snapshot as an example.. Please Which [art you want to colors and how ?

Comment: Any particular column you want color.. or more than one column. Please put this information I am not able to help you. Once updated, let me know

Comment: @rakshit: i want to color all the cells filled with the data

Comment: I can see 2 colors... which data you want to color as yellow ? What's the logic

Comment: i need to color the entire data....at present there are two colors i need only one...completely yellow sheet

Comment: Ok... Full sheet as *yellow*... `Row1..RowN` and `Col1..ColN` right ?

Comment: yes correct ..but only the cells with data in it..............

Comment: Wait for some while.. I am doing.. Mean while the logic and relevant excel sheet post in your question. So that future users can also get benefits . Edit your post again.

Comment: Put there only one sreenshot, by saying that I want to fill all the cells color as *yellow*, if they those cells has data in it.

Comment: Once I will answer, that wouldn't match with your current post description. Make it full clear. friend.. Edit the question as I said.

Comment: Make those cells colors as Yellow which has data.... :-)

Comment: Perfect!!!... Now I will answer it.. wait for some mins.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the *MSDN* documentation of [`UsedRange Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Also see the [*56 Excel ColorIndex Colors*](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm) to verify the color index of `yellow`. Look this also [*Change cell background color using VBA*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-cell-background-color-using-vba-HA001136627.aspx) .

I use the Excel sheet as below :

[image: Before running the Ruby program :]

Here is the code :

```
require 'win32ole'

# create an instance of the Excel application object
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
# make Excel visible
excel.visible = true
# open the excel from the desired path
wb=excel.workbooks.open("C:\\Users\\test.xlsx")
# get the first Worksheet
wbs= wb.worksheets(1)
# fill the column with a specific coloe
wbs.usedrange.interior.colorindex = 6
```

[image: After running the above script]

Comment: @anurag whenever you will be having a problem in excel and ruby. post a question and ping me. I will help you. :-)